# Can someone show me how nested database structure on cloud firestore?

Tags: android, google-cloud-firestore

Im new on NoSQL database and it make me confused since im from SQL database.

I was asking about How to Edit, Add, Update and Delete on here but im having a hard time imagining the database itself.

Can someone show me a simple nested database with a picture from firestore since most of the tutorial i saw is mostly a concept or doesnt have any nested on it.
And also a simple line on how to get its reference.

Comment: How many collection/document pairs do you need?

Comment: As long it nested and can be applied to real world problem